# Set another output paths to a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xcopy, post-build-event

I'm trying to add another output path to my project, I tried to use the post build event and add a xcopy command, but the command exit with code 4, no mater the argument I use, /R, /C, /Y...

I am missing something ? I couldn't find a solution in similar questions...

[image]

Comment: Instead of Release have you tried $(Configuration) also is there a file in the target location, then add  /Y

Comment: Yes I tried that, without success, the destination directory exists and is empty

Comment: Also the same xcopy command works when tried from command line?

Comment: Its working if I use the paths explicitely, but doesn't with $(TargetDir) or $(ConfigurationName)... Its working with a cmd window, and in Visual Studio with full paths...